# why is the maximum length of path in a tournament 2 at most?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to prove a theorem which is stated as follows:

```
If G is a tournament graph and x is a vertex with the maximum out-degree, 
then for any other vertices in G, say y, there is a directed path from x
to y of length at most 2.
```

A tournament is a complete graph with directions - so I can see how a selected vertex with the highest number of outdegree can reach any other vertices within 2 steps. But I have no idea how to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ must have won at least half the games-at least half the edges from $x$ must be outward.    Assume there is a vertex $y$ that cannot be reached from $x$ in two steps.  Clearly the edge between $x$ and $y$ is directed toward $x$.  If there are $n$ participants the number of outgoing edges from $x$ is at least $\frac {n-1}2$.  If we cannot reach $y$ in two steps all the edges from $y$ to these vertices are directed from $y$.  Then the outgoing edges from $y$ number $\frac {n-1}2+1$, which is more than the number of outgoing edges from $x$, contradicting the statement that $x$ is the vertex with maximum outgoing degree.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. A quick question: why does x have at least half the edges going outward?

Comment: Count up the wins in the tournament.  There are $\frac 12n(n-1)$ games.  If every team wins less than $\frac 12(n-1)$ the total number of wins is less than $\frac 12n(n-1)$